# Android Change position of Path in canvas

Tags: android, canvas, path

**How to change position of Path in runtime?**

I have created so many shapes in canvas, I have stored all shapes in PAth array,
Just want to know how to move that shape that i have already drawn on canvas.

**I have drawn shape using path.**

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // Before "drawPath"
        canvas.drawColor(this.baseColor);

        if (this.bitmap != null) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(this.bitmap, getHeight(), getWidth(), emptyPaint);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < this.historyPointer; i++) {
            Path path = this.pathLists.get(i);
            Paint paint = this.paintLists.get(i);
            canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 0, 10, paint);
        }
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }
```

I want to change the position of that drawing text on canvas.

Please help me.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but there's the [`Path#offset()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#offset(float,%20float)) method(s).

Comment: I want to get the stored coordinate of path object,.

Comment: Again, I'm not quite sure what you mean, but there's also the [`computeBounds()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#computeBounds(android.graphics.RectF,%20boolean)) method.

Comment: I have create one shape, store that path coordinate in path object.but i want to traslate that object.

Comment: OK, that's kinda what I figured when I mentioned the `offset()` methods, which would seem to be the simplest option for you, if I'm following you correctly. Alternatively, you could `translate()` the `Canvas` instead. Or, if you don't wanna mess with the `Canvas`, yet another possibility is the [`Path#transform()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#transform(android.graphics.Matrix)) method(s), which would also let you translate, scale, rotate – all sorts of fun stuff – all in one go, if you'll eventually need those things, too.

Comment: what property do you want to animate?

Comment: @ManojPerumarath I want to move shape/text in canvas.

Comment: Create them as drawable then , you can set that to some imageview and move that